# Rust: value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop

Tags: многопоточность, процесс, rust

Хочу сделать 10 асинхронных TCP запросов в отдельных потоках, то есть под каждый запрос выделяется новый `thread`, код:

```
pub fn tcp_req(host: String, port: i64) {
    let mut conn: TcpStream;
    let mut x = 0; 
    loop {
        x += 1;
        if x == 10 {break;}

        thread::spawn(move || {
            conn = TcpStream::connect(format!("{host}:{port}", host=host, port=port)).unwrap();
            conn.write(String::from("hello\n").as_bytes()).unwrap();
        });
    }
}
```

Когда выполнятся все 10 запросов = завершение работы/break. 
**Лог компилятора:**

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `conn`
  --> src\request.rs:48:17
   |
48 |         thread::spawn(move || {
   |                       ^^^^^^^ value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop
49 |             conn = TcpStream::connect(format!("{host}:{port}", host=host.clone(), port=port.clone())).unwrap();
   |             ---- use occurs due to use in closure
   |
   = note: move occurs because `conn` has type `std::net::TcpStream`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `host`
  --> src\request.rs:48:17
   |
48 |         thread::spawn(move || {
   |                       ^^^^^^^ value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop
49 |             conn = TcpStream::connect(format!("{host}:{port}", host=host.clone(), port=port.clone())).unwrap();
   |                                                                     ---- use occurs due to use in closure
   |
   = note: move occurs because `host` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

В чем именно проблема?

Comment: Для начала я бы переместил `conn` внутрь замыкания потока, в котором оно используется, если оно не нужно вовне.

Answer (score 1):

Значение `host` имеет тип `String`, оно не размножается копированием, тогда как каждому потоку нужно свое значение, действительное на все время жизни потока. Чтобы получить десять копий, которые можно переместить каждую в свой поток, нужно в теле цикла сделать что-то вроде:

```
loop {
    let host = host.clone();
    // ...
}
```